# Create directory in external storage in Android

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to create a directory in the external storage but it is not working for me. I debugged the application there I find that code execute perfectly `myDirectory.mkdirs();` but this does not create the directory when I see it using the SD card explorer

Any idea why it is not creating the `PMS` directory in the external storage ?

```
String capturedPhotoName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";

try {
    File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/PMS/");
    if(!myDirectory.exists()) {
        myDirectory.mkdirs();
    }
    File photo = new File(myDirectory, capturedPhotoName);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_INTENT_REQUEST);
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("PMS", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: internal storage != external storage. And did you add necessary permissions?

Comment: Please edit your question. Your subject line and two lines of text say "internal" when they should say "external". So people (like me) searching SO for information about Android internal storage end up here and get frustrated.

Comment: Never mind, I've done it.

Comment: @RenniePet No I don't mind. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah really very silly mistake I made, forgot to add permission to write in the SD Card but it should have thrown the exception

Anyway, it solved my issue

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean success = (new File(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/YourAppFolderName")).mkdir(); 
        if (!success){
            Log.w("directory not created", "directory not created");
        }
```

Also in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```