# How to create a directory in root android external storage?

Tags: android, storage

I want to create a separate directory for images saved via my app. But I don't know where my code falls short. This is what I am doing to create a new directory in the root directory of external storage:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File directory = new File(root,"MYFOLDER");
if(!directory.exists()) {
    directory.mkdirs();
}
```

I have already added the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permission in my app manifest file. And I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677724/create-directory-in-external-storage-in-android), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781213/how-to-create-a-folder-in-android-external-storage-directory) and others but nothing works.

Comment: if (!directory.mkdirs()){ Toast(...could not create directory...); return;}

Comment: On Android 10 add requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to application tag in manifest file for your code to work.

Answer (score 1):

I use this which works:

```
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/mydirectory";
File Directory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);

        if (!Directory.exists()) {
            Directory.mkdirs();
        }
```

Comment: Also check return value of mkdirs

Answer (score 1):

First give runtime storage permission by adding this lines, Because after android oreo you need to give runtime permission to access storage

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }
```

then you can use this code

```
File apkStorage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "TestFolder");
 if (!apkStorage.exists()) {
        apkStorage.mkdir();
        Log.e(TAG, "Directory Created.");
}
```

Add requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" to application tag in manifest file

Comment: Yes right, Now for Android 10 you need to use Providers

Comment: Even with a FileProvider you won't be able to create a directory on the root of the external storage. only Storage Access Framework can do that.

Comment: Check the return value of mkdirs before you cry success.

Comment: So, does storage access framework work on all android API levels?

Comment: Or should I check for the device API level and perform storage actions accordingly